# How to customize sort an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of objects in JS, but it doesn't work for some reason.
The array I requested from API may contain numbers, upper and lower case letters, and some Chinese characters.

eg:

```
const arr = [
{ "title": "!Test Segment and CSV" }, 
{ "title": "&test (SC)" }, 
{ "title": "1234test (SC)" }, 
{ "title": "AAShop1 (SC)" }, 
{ "title": "AAShop2(SC)" }, 
{ "title": "ABCshop123 (SC)" },
{ "title": "adidas Outlet" },
{ "title": "AIGLE" }, 
{ "title": "American Eagle" },
{ "title": "Châteraisé" }, 
{ "title": "Tekcent" }, 
{ "title": "반찬 & COOK" },
{ "title": "始祖鸟" }, 
{ "title": "春水堂" }, 
{ "title": "稻成" }
];
```

I want it sorted according to the following rules.

1. sort a after A
2. sort B after A
3. sort Ac after ABC

   ```
    { "title": "!Test Segment and CSV" }, 
    { "title": "&test (SC)" }, 
    { "title": "1234test (SC)" }, 
    { "title": "AAShop1 (SC)" }, 
    { "title": "AAShop2(SC)" }, 
    { "title": "ABCshop123 (SC)" },
    { "title": "AIGLE" }, 
    { "title": "American Eagle" },
    { "title": "adidas Outlet" },
    { "title": "Châteraisé" }, 
    { "title": "Tekcent" }, 
    { "title": "始祖鸟" }, 
    { "title": "春水堂" }, 
    { "title": "稻成" },
    { "title": "반찬 & COOK" }
   ```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How do you expect `A` and `a` to get sorted differently, when you apply `toLowerCase` to both of them? You are effectively testing `'a' > 'a'` now.

Comment: Noted and thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 2):

`.sort()` and `.localeCompare()`. Note, in the OP, the input array is already sorted correctly so in this answer I have jumbled the order of the input array to demonstrate that the code functions correctly.

```js
const data = [{ "title": "BB" }, { "title": "Ac" }, { "title": "adidas" }, { "title": "AA" }, { "title": "Ba" }, { "title": "ABC" }];

const output = data.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: The question asks for 'A' to come before  'a', but localCompare appears to do the opposite.  However, for the other requirements it seems to work.

Comment: @Yogi "*The question asks for 'A' to come before 'a', but localCompare appears to do the opposite.*" that's the order I'm seeing here - first is "AA" then "adidas" is fourth. Tried it in both Firefox and Chrome. Where are you seeing the opposite order?

Comment: The array I requested from API may contain numbers, upper and lower case letters, and some Chinese characters. I already tried your method, but failed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to sort it on lower case.

```js
    let myArr = [{ "title": "AA" }, { "title": "ABC" }, { "title": "Ac" }, { "title": "adidas" }, { "title": "Ba" }, { "title": "BB" }]
    let sortList = myArr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.title.toLowerCase() > b.title.toLowerCase()
    })
    console.log(sortList)
```

Comment: [Sorting in JavaScript: Shouldn't returning a boolean be enough for a comparison function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785)

Comment: I've updated my question and it would be great if you could help answer it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that without manipulating a string into a `lowerCase` with the only help of a simple [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let myArr = [{ "title": "AA" }, { "title": "ABC" }, { "title": "Ac" }, { "title": "adidas" }, { "title": "Ba" }, { "title": "BB" }];

let sortedArr = myArr.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.title - b.title
});

console.log(sortedArr);
```

Comment: I've updated my question and it would be great if you could help answer it. thanks.